# Consistency of the extremum estimators

Tags: maximum-likelihood, consistency

I am trying to understand intuitively the assumptions mentioned in the following theorem:

*Theorem.* If there is a function $Q_0(\theta)$ s.t. (i) $Q_0(\theta)$ is uniquely maximized at $\theta_0$; (ii) $\Theta$ is compact; (iii) $Q_0(\theta)$ is continuous; (iv) $\hat{Q}_n(\theta)$ converges uniformly in probability to $Q_0(\theta)$, then $\hat{\theta} \rightarrow \theta_0$ in probability.

I understand that the last assumption says that $\hat{Q}_n(\theta)$ is between $Q_0(\theta) - \varepsilon$ and $Q_0(\theta) + \varepsilon$. for some $\varepsilon$. Thus, given assumption (i) we can find $\theta_L < \theta_0 < \theta_U$ s.t. $\hat{\theta} \in (\theta_L, \theta_U)$.   Does assumption (i) guarantee that $|\theta_0| \neq \infty$? Why intuitively assumptions (ii) and (iii) are needed?

Comment: Compactness implies closed on a metric space, so (ii) is what guarantees that $|\theta_0| \neq \infty$.

Comment: @jbowman What does go wrong if $|\theta_0| = \infty$?

Comment: This is the consistency theorem for Extremum Estimators in general (of which M-estimators are a subset). It would be useful to modify the title of the question accordingly.

Comment: You can't converge in probability to infinity, it's always infinitely far away from any real number, so your estimator isn't going to be consistent.

Comment: @jbowman makes perfect sense. Do you have any idea how I can interpret closed parameter space and continuity intuitively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP asked for "intuitive" explanations of the assumptions, but what's "intuitive" varies greatly from person to person. So I will provide **a view of these assumptions as a "reasonable framework" in order to *examine* consistency of the extremum estimator**, and not as a set of assumptions that are designed to be sufficient for consistency. In my eyes at least, this is an interesting way to gain "intuition" on them.

The extremum estimator $\hat \theta_n$ is defined as (I am indexing the estimator also with $n$ for a reason),

$$\hat \theta_n : Q_n(\hat \theta_n) = \max_{\theta \in \Theta}Q_n(\theta) \tag{1}$$

*And how do we know that $\hat \theta_n$ exists? How do we know that $Q_n(\cdot) $ has a maximum in $\Theta$?*

We *don't*: In order to guarantee it we have to assume that a) $Q_n(\cdot) $ is continuous in $\theta$ and **b) that $\Theta$ is compact.** (since compactness of the set from which the argument of the function takes its values is *equivalent* to the existence of a maximum of a continuous function in this set).
This is the first and foremost reason why we assume that the parameter space is compact (together with continuity of $Q_n(\cdot)$: to **guarantee the *existence* of the extremum estimator** -but it will serve us in other aspects too.

Moreover, since "the limit function $Q_0(\theta)$ is uniquely maximized at $\theta_0$" appears as an assumption, then, together with compactness of $\Theta$ *imply* the continuity of $Q_0(\cdot)$ (**so assumption (iii) in the question is in reality redundant**, although it is usually stated as an additional assumption).

So why do we make the assumption that **"the limit function $Q_0(\cdot)$  is uniquely maximized at $\theta_0$?"** I would offer the following intuition: **In order to "target" the unknown parameter of interest, it must possess some distinctive characteristic, on which to base the targeting**. So we *start* by finding a limit function $Q_0(\cdot)$ such that $\theta_0$ has a special role in relation to it, compared to other values in the parameter space. One such special role is for $\theta_0$ to be the unique $\text{argmax}$ of $Q_0(\cdot)$. Then in a sense we apply the "sample analogue" principle, and obtain $Q_n(\cdot)$ as the sample analogue of $Q_0(\cdot)$, and $\hat \theta_n$ as the sample analogue of $\theta_0$. And *then* we examine what additional conditions may be needed in order to guarantee the desired convergence of the sample analogue to the population counterpart.

What is left is the assumption **"$Q_n(\cdot)$ converges uniformly in probability to $Q_0(\cdot)$"**. To assume convergence per se appears naturally necessary -if $Q_n(\cdot)$ did not converge, or if it converged to some other function than $Q_0(\cdot)$, how could we relate $\hat \theta_n$ and $\theta_0$? But why do we need *uniform* convergence, and not just the weaker *pointwise* convergence?

Pointwise convergence (in probability) is defined as

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P\left(\Big|Q_n(\theta)-Q_0(\theta)\Big|< \epsilon\right) =1,\;\;\epsilon>0,\;\; \forall\, \theta \in \Theta \tag{1}$$

while Uniform convergence as

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P\left(\sup_{\theta \in \Theta}\Big|Q_n(\theta)-Q_0(\theta)\Big|< \epsilon\right) =1,\;\;\epsilon>0   \tag{2}$$

In pointwise convergence, we *fix* $\theta$ and then consider what happens as $n\rightarrow \infty$. If the limiting probability result holds for all $\theta$ (but *each examined separately*) then we have pointwise convergence.

In Uniform convergence, we form a sequence with the suprema of the function, and examine whether this sequence converges. And as $n$ changes, $\hat \theta_n$ in general changes, a fact that places what we are interested in studying *outside the scope of pointwise convergence*. Under pointwise convergence, we could not even write the probability statement using $\hat \theta_n$ -since the argument of $Q_n(\cdot)$ should remain fixed.

So we could say that **the assumption of uniform convergence** is not a matter of "how strong we need the convergence to be" - but, to begin with, **a matter of assuming a form of convergence in the context of which we could indeed examine what we want to examine.**

Up to now therefore, all assumptions made (and some regarding measurability with respect to the data that have been left unstated), appear mostly to be assumptions that permit us to *consider whether* we have convergence of $\hat \theta_n$ to $\theta_0$, and perhaps to have a "reasonable belief that we *may* obtain convergence"... They do *not* appear to be assumptions that guarantee (are sufficient for) the desired convergence result...

**The impressive thing about it, is that these assumptions are also sufficient for consistency of the extremum estimator $\hat \theta_n$.**